# Centering divs rendered as tables through css

Tags: html, css

I am unable render my divs in the center of the page (horizontally). I have tried styling the CSS as "margin:auto" but still not rendering correctly.

Here is my CSS:

```
.pbtable
{
    display:table;
    margin: auto 0;
    width:500px;
}
.pbrow
{
    display:table-row;
}
.pbcell
{
    display:table-cell;

}
```

Here is my html:

```
<body>
        <?php echo $menu;?>

        <br/><br/><br/>
        <div class="pbdtable">
            <div class="pbrow">
                <div class="pbcell">
                    <img src="/images/forevents/mcdougall.jpg" height="200px"/>
                </div>
                <div class="pbcell">
                    <img src="/images/forevents/targetJoAnn.jpg" height="200px"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pbrow">
                <div class="pbcell">
                    Dr. John McDougall
                </div>
                <div class="pbcell">
                    JoAnne Farb
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

The  two images appear to the far left of the screen and I would like them centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:** wrong class name

In your CSS it is written `.pbtable` but in HTML it's `pbdtable`

**Problem 2:** you need the `margins` to be `auto` on the right and left sides, you wrote `auto 0` instead of `0 auto`.

Final correct code:

```css
.pbtable {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}
.pbrow {
  display: table-row;
}
.pbcell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="pbtable">
  <div class="pbrow">
    <div class="pbcell">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/200/200" height="200px">
    </div>
    <div class="pbcell">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/200/200" height="200px">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pbrow">
    <div class="pbcell">
      Dr. John McDougall
    </div>
    <div class="pbcell">
      JoAnne Farb
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/Lfh0hg7o/

Comment: Yes sir! That is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need `position: relative` on the `.pbtable`element (and also on its parent element) for `margin: 0 auto` to do the centering.

Addition: There were two errors in your code:

1.) It's `margin: 0 auto`, not `margin: auto 0`

2.) You had a typo in your class for the table: "pbdtable" vs. "pbtable"

Here is a codepen with the working solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKJJvz

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. I added the position element and changed the margin and it is still not centering.

Comment: I just tried surrounding the divs with <center> tags and that seemed to work... seems like there would be a css way

Answer (score 0):

Just align the images to the center.

```
.pbrow {
    display: table-row;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3gLj4pm/)